# Which Scottish regiment is the Queen inspecting in this photo?

Tags: identification, uniform, scotland

Among some photos & newspaper cuttings found in a relative's study after he died, was the photo below, which seems to show the late Queen inspecting a guard of honour wearing Scottish uniforms.

Is it possible to identify the regiment in question?

This photo would have been taken between 1955 and 1975, and probably around the Stirling/Falkirk area.

[image: Queen inspects a group of kilt clad soldiers]

There is nothing on the back. It looks more like a cutting from a book or a poster, rather than the original photo, but unfortunately the other face doesn't give any further hints.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The tartan is not clear and the [glengarry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glengarry)  was shared by most Highland regiments. The hose and sporrans may have differed among regiments but I am having a hard time nailing down exactly which aspects would be indicative.

However, I would punt a guess at the [Argyll & Sutherland Highlanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argyll_and_Sutherland_Highlanders) - despite the name, their recruiting area included Stirling and Falkirk, with the depot at Stirling and TA companies in both. So they seem the likely candidate on geographic grounds. In addition, the Argyll badge broadly fits the shape of the one in the picture (roughly circular with a little point at the top).

Edit: a different event, but [this page](http://argylls1945to1971.co.uk/AandSH_Balmoral1962.htm) has pictures from the Argylls mounting guard at Balmoral in 1962, and [this photo](https://www.alamy.com/the-queen-inspects-the-1st-battalion-and-argyll-sutherland-highlanders-at-catterick-garrison-9th-november-1978-image465011257.html) is from an inspection at Catterick in 1978; the uniforms are a good match for what we see here including the hose, badge and sporran).

Given the spectators are looping around behind the soldiers,they're sat quite close, and that they're not on a parade ground, I would guess this is perhaps not a full-scale military event like these

Two points that might help date it but I can't draw a direct conclusion from them - firstly, it's hard to tell from the angle but I *think* they are carrying older style rifles (no box magazines like in the 1962/78 photos), which may lean towards it being early. Secondly, only one of the men is wearing any medals - no widespread campaign medals.

Comment: Great answer. Some of my family were in the Black Watch and these are not Black Watch uniforms as they don't have the red hackle.

Comment: Definitely Argyll and Sutherland, you can tell by the sporrans.  Every regiment has their own design.  The six white tassels are a dead give-away. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argyll_and_Sutherland_Highlanders#/media/File:Argyll_&_Sutherland_Highlanders_recruiting_poster_1914.jpg